# get repository from Admin Class SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I work with symfony 2.8 and SonataAdminBundle, I want to view the users who are 'client' and here is my code:

**ClientAdmin**

```
 protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{

     $result = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('Doctrine')->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findClient();

    $listMapper

        ->add('client', 'sonata_type_model', array(
            'empty_value' => '', 
            'choice_list' => $result))

              ;
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
public function findClient()
{   $dql = "SELECT p FROM UserBundle:User p WHERE p.type LIKE 'client' ORDER BY p.id DESC";
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)

        ->getResult();
}
```

But it does not work and still no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the list query thanks to the createQuery method :

```
    <?php

public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->andWhere(
        $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAliases()[0] . '.my_field', ':my_param')
    );
    $query->setParameter('my_param', 'my_value');
    return $query;
}
```

[Sonata Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list)